# n-step composition of a homographic function ; proof by induction

Tags: induction

**Prove that $f_n (l) = \frac{l}{l(n+1)+1}$ for all positive integers n.**

**If $f_{n+1}=f_0 \circ f_n$ and $f_{0} (l)=\frac{l}{l+1}$ for $n= 0,1,2,3....$**

This proof has to be solved with the method of induction. Now, I ran into a problem with base cases. For the $f_n (l)$ the base case is 1 or n=1, but the base case for $f_{n+1}$ is $n=0$. So I don't know how to take this further or I might be completely thinking wrong.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order that it reflects the content of your question.

Answer (score 2):

The base case is in fact $n=0$ for which you need to prove that $$f_1=f_0Of_0$$since $$f_0Of_0(l)={f_0(l)\over f_0(l)+1}={{l\over l+1}\over {l\over l+1}+1}={l\over l+l+1}={l\over 2l+1}=f_1(l)$$hence the induction is complete.

Comment: how would i do n=k and n= k+1

Comment: Just prove that$${{l\over (n+1)l+1}\over {l\over (n+1)l+1}+1}={l\over (n+2)l+1}$$

Comment: i am not satisfied with this answer mainly because in the first base case you had n=0 for $f_{n+1}$ but this will produce $f_1$, now if we took base case as n = 0 then $f_0 (l)$ will produce $l/(l+1)$ which is not verified to be $f_1$

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients you are looking for are those you find in the matrix power :

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\n&1\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

Therefore, your final composition of functions is

$$f(\ell):=\dfrac{\ell}{n\ell+1}\tag{2}$$

This is due to the classical correspondence :

$$f(x):=\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d} \ \ \leftrightarrow \ \ M_f=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

which induces a homomorphism between composition of "homographic" functions and matrix product (up to a factor)

$$f_1 \circ f_2  \ \ \leftrightarrow \ \ M_{f_1}M_{f_2}$$

Proof : (I take $x$ instead of $\ell$, not usual).

$$\dfrac{a \tfrac{ex+f}{gx+h} +b}{c\tfrac{ex+f}{gx+h} +d}=\dfrac{a(ex+f)+b(gx+h)}{c(ex+f)+d(gx+h)}=\dfrac{(ae+bg)x+(af+bh)}{(ce+dg)x+(cf+dh)}$$

where you recognize the coefficients of the product of matrices :

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}.$$

Caution : The last equality in (1) necessitates a (rather easy) reasoning by induction.

Comment: I dont know about this method, because my class recently started matrix and we have only been introduced to solve simultaneous equation.

Comment: it will be nice if you could explain how u got the starting matrix

Comment: is there another way?

Comment: You can do a direct recurrence to show relationship (2).